# Adblock blocking images

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, adblock

I have developed a MVC4 application. In this application the user can place an advertisement which other users can view and place a bid.

I personally have adblocker installed on chrome. The client I made the product for doesn't experience problems, but I (and other users with adblock) do.

I know it has something to do with the names of my images/applicationfolders, even the controllernames, but these names are the only logical to choose because it is an advertisement application.

Do I need to change the names of all directories/images/applicationcontrollers or is there another way around?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the image file names causing the issue, Adblock looks for images with common banner sizes in the file and/or path name.

Eg. '/image_728x90.png' '/728x90/imgid.jpg' and so on.

The first thing I'd try is renaming images and paths, let us know  if that works.

Adblock Plus on Firefox allows you to see which items are blocked and the filters that are blocking them. In Firefox look for the Adblock icon, left click and 'Open blockable items'. It's probably similar in Chrome but I don't have Adblock installed on that browser.

Also note that not all users will be using the same filters, you can download various filter definition files, and create your own custom filters.

Comment: My images don't have these names, they just have names like car.png, house.jpg etc...

Comment: Can you show a full example image URI so we can take a look. Perhaps even a working page if the site is live.